# Android Reflection Method Error

Tags: java, android, reflection

I'm trying to figure out Reflection with this Android class:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils");
Method method = c.getDeclaredMethod("getKeyguardStoredPasswordQuality");
method.setAccessible(true);
Object object = method.invoke(c); // Error with this line
result = object.toString());
```

The method `getKeyguardStoredPasswordQuality` is declared as (no parameters):

```
public int getKeyguardStoredPasswordQuality() {
    // codes here
}
```

The error I got is:

```
Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected receiver of type com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils, but got java.lang.Class<com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils>
```

How do I declare `com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils` as a receiver?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are passing the `class` to `#invoke()` instead of an instance of `LockPatternUtils`.

You can create an instance using [`#newInstance()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29).

Comment: Can you expand on your answer as doing this `Object clazz = c.newInstance();` then pass clazz in `Object object = method.invoke(clazz);` will only work if the constructor of the referenced class is empty. What do you do in the case where the constructor of the class is defined as `public LockPatternUtils(Context context) {..}`?

Comment: I will mark your answer as correct by showing me the doco to the `newInstance` method. Thanks, mate.

Comment: @ChuongPham: Sure, there are some limitations, but they are documented in the API I link to.

Comment: This same error occurs when using the get() method without newInstance(). So it should be:

`MyObj v = (MyObj) field.get(clazz.newInstance());`

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I've figured it out. I've adapted the codes below based on this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html).

In case anyone is interested in the solution, here it is:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils");
Constructor<?>[] constructors = c.getDeclaredConstructors();
Constructor<?> constructor = null;
for (int i = 0; i < constructors.length; i++) {
   constructor = constructors[i];
   if (constructor.getGenericParameterTypes().length == 0)
      break;
}
constructor.setAccessible(true);
Object clazz = constructor.newInstance(context, true);
Method method = clazz.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getKeyguardStoredPasswordQuality");
Object object = method.invoke(clazz);
result = object.toString();
```

The above solution requires that the public constructor of `LockPatternUtils.java` class to be defined as:

```
public LockPatternUtils(Context context) {...}
```

If the constructor changes in the future (after 2013), the solution will need to be amended.

*Note: The above is an exercise for me to understand the usage of Reflection. However, using Reflection in Android production apps should be used sparingly and when absolutely needed.*

Comment: I had to slightly change the code to get it running on my Andorid 5.1.1 device and get the right constructor used.
Had to change if (constructor.getGenericParameterTypes().length == 0)