# Invoke getMessageWaitingIndicator count of PhoneBase.java

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am trying to retrieve count of voicemail .For this I am trying to call `getMessageWaitingIndicator`  method of PhoneBase.java.
My Code is as given below

```
Class<?> class2=Class.forName("com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneBase");
Method method=class2.getMethod("getMessageWaitingIndicator");
Boolean returnValue=(Boolean) method.invoke(class2);
```

But Everytime I am getting an exception as mentioned below :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: expected receiver of type com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneBase, 
but got java.lang.class<com.android.internal.telephony.PhoneBase>
```

I don't understand it. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: In what line did the exception happen?

Comment: Boolean returnValue=(Boolean) method.invoke(class2);--this line

Comment: You need to pass the instance of `PhoneBase`... but you are passing it's reflected class...

Comment: How to pass instance of Phonebase ? can you guide me please. I never used reflection. Also PhoneBase is a abstract class how to get it's instance.

Answer (score 0):

The instruction:

```
method.invoke (stringValue);
```

needs the object in which the `method` will be invoked.

```
method = class2.getMethod('myFunction',String.class);
method.invoke(someInstanceOfMyActivity, stringValue);
```

Documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html

Edit.
You can also look at the answer to the very close question here:

[Android Reflection Method Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740885/android-reflection-method-error)

Comment: Sorry but i can not understand what you mean? Can you tell me what modification I need to do to make my code work?